# displaying alert to all the private route when user non logged in user tries to visit private route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two route `private` and `public route` in my react js application. I want to know is it possible to display alert to all the private route when not logged in user try to visit private route. I don't want to do inside every private component.
I tried by myself but it starts to alert on every page when user is not logged in.

> This is my Private route code.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  // console.log("restprivate", rest);
  const { changeBottomNavBar, tansformToButton, changeHeaderForOrder } = rest;
  //console.log("loggedin", Store.getState().user.data.loggedIn);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100wv" }}>
      <HeaderContainer
        privateHeader={true}
        changeHeaderForOrder={changeHeaderForOrder}
      />
      <TermsOfUse />
      <PrivacyPolicy />
      <VendorTerms />
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          Store.getState().user.data.loggedIn ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Component {...props} />
          )
        }
      />
      <Mobile>
        {changeBottomNavBar ? (
          <BottomNavBarContainer />
        ) : (
          <BottomNavBar tansformToButton={tansformToButton} />
        )}
      </Mobile>
      <Desktop>
        <Footer />
      </Desktop>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the `Route` component `render` callback to check the `loggedIn` value and trigger an alert before returning the component to render.

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={(props) => {
    const { loggedIn } = Store.getState().user.data;
    !loggedIn && alert('This is a private Route');
    return loggedIn ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Component {...props} /> // <-- Why return same Component?
    )
  }}
/>
```